# Check if time is between a time range, but also if the user only gives start or end time

Tags: javascript

I have the user picking start and end times, and am trying to make an if statement that filters out all of the data that isn't within their time range.

```
    var startT = start date set by user
    var endT   = end date set by user
    var dbTime = some datetime in database
```

I know that an if statement like the following will check between a specified date (assuming the user sets both a start and  end time):

```
    if (dbTime > startT && dbTime < endT ){
     //do something
    }
```

I'm blanking on how to check all conditions scenarios without making this a giant if statement. So if a user just wants to see everything before a certain date, only specifying an end time but not a start time, it will still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((!startT || dbTime >= startT) && (!endT || dbTime <= endT))
```

That should do the trick. Basically, for each condition, you either filter based on that value, or you let it go through if you don't have that value.

For example, if I just give an `endT` of `2010-01-01`, then all records that have a time less than or equal to that will work. Doesn't matter have much less it is.

Comment: I don't know how the OP is representing their time, but if it is an integer timestamp, I'd be concerned about excluding the case where `startT` or `endT` are exactly the epoch `0` time, since `0` will be treated the same as `undefined`. (If they're comparing strings of the form `YYYY-MM-DD` or similar -- whose lexical sorting is valid time sorting -- then this concern does not apply.)

Comment: @apsillers The comparison is through strings (sorry for the lack of specification there) so it works out! I was close but I think I was just overthinking things. Much appreciated!

Comment: @apsillers You are technically correct, but I'd say in 99.9% of cases, you usually don't have a time at the start of epoch if you are worried about start and end dates. If it was a concern, you could simply use `(!startT && startT !== 0)` instead of just `!startT`.

Comment: @user7526001 Yeah, dates are always annoying to work with. Not sure why they are always so difficult to get your brain around, but they are.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you need to handle three top level cases:

```
1. User defines start date and end date
2. User only defines end date
3. User only defines start date
```

I'm going to assume that your variables will be `undefined` or `null` if your user does not specify the date. In that case, there are three top-level `if` conditions to handle your query. Something like the following should work:

```
if (startT && endT) {
 // handle all timestamps in between the range
   if (dbTime > startT && dbTime < endT ){
     //do something
   }
} else if (!startT && endT && dbTime < endT) {
 //handle everything before end timestamp
} else if (startT && dbTime > startT) {
 // handle everything after start timestamp
}
```